# My ASP.NET website is not displayed correctly in Internet Explorer 10 after server deployment

Tags: asp.net, localhost, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

I've created a website using ASP.NET (C#) Framework 4.0

When running on my local IIS (in debug/release - before and after deployed) - the website is displayed correctly - as intended (checked on Internet Explorer 9, 10, Chrome and FireFox)

After I've deployed the website to my server (Windows Server 2008 DataCenter - Amazon hosting) - and **only in IE 10** - the website is **NOT** displayed correctly - spacing is sometimes wrong, background colors sometimes disappeared, links not working properly, padding/margin is missing in some of the places and more... - it seems like the styles/CSS are partial... On other browsers (Chrome/FireFox/IE9) - it is displayed correctly (as intended)

I've tried to add the compatibility meta tags to IE=9 - didn't work (by the way, in IE10 - if I open the F12 tool - and change the **Browser Mode** to IE9 - it works!, but if I just change the Document Mode - it doesn't seem to help)

Why is Internet Explorer 10 evil??? Has anyone encountered this issue? any suggestions?

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you write you are using *F12 tools*. My experience is that with *Developer Tools* running IE10 often does not apply all CSS rules (especially in at the end of external files). Refreshing the page or closing F12 tools usualy solves the problem. Also if you know which style is not applied it helps to disable and enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

i have passe through a similar situation and some things just don't stay they way i want in every browser, so perhaps the better way out is to create CSS hacks tos specific spacing or styling issues you may have encoutered.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/

Comment: Hi rodrigorf - If that was the case so it was ok, but the case is that in the same Internet Explorer 10 - when I look at the website in my localhost - it looks fine, when I look at the website on the server - it is not fine... and I don't understand why - I don't think it is a matter of CSS, maybe security or something...

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and frustration, I've found the solution to my problem (here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/App_BrowsersUpdate)

Apparently the website should be updated to allow IE10 compatibility...

In your solution - install the ASP.NET Browser Capabilities Update using the following command in the "Package Manager Console" (can be started from "Tools"->"Library Package Manager" in your VS): 
**Install-Package App_BrowsersUpdate**
(this will add ".browser" files to your website and few lines in your "web.config" file)

Rebuild and re-deploy your website and that's it! now my deployed website looks as intended on IE10!

(I still don't understand why it worked correctly on my localhost and not on the web server but at least the problem is solved)